# Phoenix - Get current path in controller

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I get the current route path from within the controller?

I know Phoenix generates prefixed helpers like `users_path()` for a route `/users/:id`, however that does not seem right for my case because we shouldn't have to use a prefix that may later change when working within the route's controller.

Comment: You mean the path as a plain string? Try `conn.request_path`.

Comment: To access it inside a template I used `assigns.conn.request_path` (based on @Dogbert comment)

Answer (score 2):

As of [Phoenix 1.3.0.rc.1](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) you can use [`current_path`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/aeccae9658ed3d85d8af8f28ce2584d407b43d6b/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L1280) and [`current_url`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/aeccae9658ed3d85d8af8f28ce2584d407b43d6b/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L1335) to get the current path or url respectively.

```
  iex> current_url(conn)
  "https://www.example.com/users/123?existing=param"

  iex> current_url(conn, %{new: "param"})
  "https://www.example.com/users/123?new=param"

  iex> current_url(conn, %{})
  "https://www.example.com/users/123"
```